# Both Threads stuck on wait condition in Java

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronized

I have a server and two clients, the server starts two Threads (ServerHandler) which both are passed the `Socket` TCP connection of the corresponding clients which connect to the Server at the beginning.

**Expected behavior:**
One ServerHandler Threads sends a message to the client, while the other ServerHandler Thread waits `wait()` ... then the working Thread notifies the sleeping Thread and waits... And so forth.

**Actual behavior:**
Both ServerHandlers wait at the same time. They both enter the synchronized block which shouldn't be the case, one Thread should be waiting while the other works.

**Code snippet of a ServerHandler (two instances of it are running)**

```
private static Object lock = new Object();
...
@Override
public void run() {
    System.out.println(String.format("  --> Server handler: %s is in run method...", serverID));
    while (true) {
        synchronized (lock){
            while (!Server.isFinished()) {
                try {
                    System.out.println(String.format("  --> Server handler: %s is waiting...", serverID));
                    lock.wait();
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
                }
            }
            System.out.println(String.format("  --> Server handler: %s is ready to send board...", serverID));
            Server.setFinished(true);
            sendBoard();

            notify();
        }
    }
}
```

**Note:**
The `Server` class starts both ServerHandler Threads. `finished` is set `false` by default

**Output:**

```
CLIENT connected!
<-- I'M Alan I want to play!
--> Server handler 1 instantiated!
CLIENT connected!
<-- I'M Bot I want to play!
--> Server handler 2 instantiated!
HANDLER started...
HANDLER started...
--> Server handler: 1 is in run method...
--> Server handler: 2 is in run method...
--> Server handler: 1 is waiting...
--> Server handler: 2 is waiting...
```

**Expected behavior:**

```
CLIENT connected!
<-- I'M Bot I want to play!
--> Server handler 1 instantiated!
CLIENT connected!
<-- I'M Alan I want to play!
--> Server handler 2 instantiated!
HANDLER started...
HANDLER started...
--> Server handler: 1 is in run method...
--> Server handler: 1 is waiting...
--> Server handler: 2 is in run method...
--> Server handler: 2 is ready to send board...
...
```

Thanks!

Comment: so you have ServerHandler instances s1 and s2; s1 calls s1.wait(), s2 calls s2.wait(). Who calls s1.notify() ?

Comment: I thought the first accessing the sync block would block it and would actually send the board What's my fault?

Comment: the first thread to enter the synchronized block finds that Server.isFinished()=false and calls wait(). (see https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#wait()). So this thread goes in waiting state (it is paused), and *releases* the monitor. The next thread acquires the monitor and goes into waiting state, too.

Comment: though actually - do they call `synchronized(this)`? in that case, each server-handler listens on his own monitor (and can only be woken up but notifying exctly that monitor).

Comment: I now have created a static Object lock in the Server handlers and I synchronize on this object. But still same problem. Would setting the finished var. before waiting the solution?

Comment: can you post the updated code?

Comment: When that code calls `wait`, precisely what is it waiting for and where did it check that it didn't happen already? (It's always a bug to wait for something that already happened -- you'll be waiting forever!)

Comment: @DavidSchwartz I updated the code

Answer (score 0):

Can you provide some examples of what is your expected output?

One thing that seems like an accidental mistake is that both threads have their own lock, instead of having one shared (notice the **static**).

Another thing that does not make sense is calling [notify](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#notify--) on a lock that you already own.

```java
private static Object lock = new Object();

public void run() {
    while (true) {
        synchronized (lock) {
            while (!Server.isFinished()) {
                try {
                    lock.wait();
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
                }
            }

            Server.setFinished(true);
            sendBoard();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I edited my question (See expected behavior) When I locked them on a static object (as you wrote) a Exception in thread "Thread-0" java.lang.IllegalMonitorStateException is thrown (At the `wait()`  statement)

Comment: Can you try again? The exception is thrown only when you call `wait()` on a lock you don't own. In this case `lock.wait()` is clearly called inside `synchronized (lock)` block and therefore must be owned.

Comment: I tried 5 times, always a IllegaMonitor... Exception

Comment: You sure you've changed  `synchronized (this)` to  `synchronized (lock)`?

Comment: UPDATE: I forget to write `lock.wait()` Exception is not there anymore, but still the Threads are  both waiting simultaneously

Answer (score 0):

Not sure you are using the correct synchronization mechanism here.

Your flow goes as follows

1. Thread 1 grabs monitor
2. Thread 1 checks server status
3. Server not ready
4. Thread 1 drops monitor and waits
5. Thread 2 grabs monitor
6. Thread 2 checks server status
7. Server not ready
8. Thread 2 drops monitor and waits
9. Deadlock as both threads are waiting on each other

The threads can therefore never get past the server checks as no one one will notify that they can proceed. For that to be possible you need either Thread 1 or Thread 2 to notify the other one when both are ready, resulting in a deadlock.

You might want to consider using for example a [Cyclic Barrier](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CyclicBarrier.html) instead. This will let you wait until you have gathered enough threads to start a game.

```
private static Object lock = new Object();
private static CyclicBarrier barrier = new CyclicBarrier(2, () -> setReady());
...
@Override
public void run() {
    System.out.println(String.format("  --> Server handler: %s is in run method...", serverID));
    while (true) {
        synchronized (lock){
            while (!Server.isFinished()) {
                try {
                    System.out.println(String.format("  --> Server handler: %s is waiting...", serverID));
                    lock.wait();
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
                }
           }
           System.out.println(String.format("  --> Server handler: %s is ready to send board...", serverID));

            sendBoard();

            notify();
        }
    }
}

public static void setReady() {
    synchronized (lock) {
        try {
            sendBoard();
            System.out.println(String.format("  --> Server handler: %s is waiting...", serverID));
            lock.notify();
            lock.wait();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
        }
    }
}
```

Something like this would let you change block until both threads start, the second thread reaches the barrier then triggers the setReady method sending the board before waiting on the other thread.

Comment: Will this result that one Thread plays, while the other waits, then the working thread goes to sleep and the one who was sleeping goes in work mode (and so on) That's what I want to achieve?

Comment: No, this only solves getting enough players which seemed to be the issue. Let me update the answer with some setup for that.

Comment: I just want them not to play simultaneously... That's why I always have to lock one thread while the other one works

Comment: Updated with a blocking barrier. Not sure this is optimal though, you might just want a simpler mutex/semaphore that blocks the first thread then moves on to the next one.

Answer (score 0):

You must call `notify` on `lock` object.

Comment: I did try it `lock.notify();` but it didn't change anything